# Laravel CKEditor5 - ClassicEditor is not Defined

Tags: php, laravel, webpack, laravel-6, ckeditor5

I'm trying to replace an old version of CKEditor in a Laravel app due to dependency incompatibility with `unisharp/laravel-ckeditor` and Laravel 6. I've found the CKEditor 5 page with NPM installation instructions, but haven't been able to get it working. Here is my code:

`resources/main.js`

```
require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic');

$(document).ready(function(){
  ClassicEditor.create($('#edit_about_text').get()[0]);
});
```

`webpack.mix.js`

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/main.js', 'public/js');
```

`layouts/master.blade.php`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head></head>
<body>
  <script src="{{ asset('js/main.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`jQuery` is included (somehow; somewhat unfamiliar with `webpack`), but running a page that extends `@extends('layouts.master')` results in the following:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ClassicEditor is not defined

If I remove the `require()` statement from `main.js` and simply use the `CDN` link, everything works as expected:

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/16.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/main.js') }}"></script>
```

I'm doing something wrong, but I'm at a loss... Has anyone seen this issue before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite a simple solution that the documentation fails to reference, but you need to assign the value of `require()` to `ClassicEditor`:

```
var ClassicEditor = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic');
```

Doing so allows correct reference in code.

Comment: And how would it be if I wanted to import a library? For example the "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-code-block/src/codeblock" ?

Answer (score 4):

Regarding Laravel included libraries examples in `boostrap.js` file such as `pusher`, `axios`, etc...

You may use

```
window.ClassicEditor = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic');

$(document).ready(function(){
  ClassicEditor.create($('#edit_about_text').get()[0]);
});
```

Comment: remember to add mix.combine([
    'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js'
],'public/js/jquery.js'); to webpack.mix.js and include jquery. otherwise $ not defined error will be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers helped me alot. But for me I had to do some extra works to make it work. So I am sharing it here for the visiting users.

- My Laravel version did not have jquery loaded so had to load it.
- I did not want to add ckeditor to my app.js bundle as it will be used in a single page of my website. So wanted to load it for that page only

created new `ckeditor.js` file in `resources/js/` folder with following content

```
window.ClassicEditor = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic');
```

added the created file and jquery to `webpack.mix.js` to compile. If you want you can combine to one file, but it wont be good if you want to use jquery for other purposes.

```
mix.combine([
    'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js'
    //here you can include more files to combine, or can combine ckeditor file here as well
],'public/js/jquery.js');

mix.js('resources/js/ckeditor.js', 'public/js/ckeditor.js');
```

loaded the compiled to the page. Assuming that you are using blade template extending main blade file which has a  `@yield('page-head-scripts')` inside head tag. There are other approaches for this step, this is how I did it.

```
@section('page-head-scripts')
      <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
      <script src="{{ asset('js/ckeditor.js') }}"></script>
@endsection
```

Add the editor create code to the page. Assuming that you are using blade template extending main blade file which has a  `@yield('page-last-scripts')` end of the main page. There are other approaches for this step, this is how I did it.

```
@section('page-last-scripts')
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

  //ClassicEditor.create($('#edit_about_text').get()[0]); this or below part.
  //to elobrate I have added more codes
  ClassicEditor.create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
        toolbar: [ 'heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'blockQuote' ],
        heading: {
            options: [
                { model: 'paragraph', title: 'Paragraph', class: 'ck-heading_paragraph' },
                { model: 'heading1', view: 'h1', title: 'Heading 1', class: 'ck-heading_heading1' },
                { model: 'heading2', view: 'h2', title: 'Heading 2', class: 'ck-heading_heading2' }
            ]
        }
    } )
    .catch( error => {
        console.log( error );
    } );

});

</script>
@endsection
```

Comment: Cheers for the great explanation on all the required steps :) I (obviously) took some liberties in assuming what had already been done (since they had been for my situation), but it's definitely helpful to show the full approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
ClassicEditor = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic');

document.querySelectorAll('[data-init-plugin="ckeditor"]').forEach(function (val) {
    ClassicEditor
        .create(val, {
            toolbar: ['bold', 'italic', 'link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList'],
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
});
```